# execution time not showing in vs c++ 2010

Tags: c++

in visual c++ 2010 I'm timing the execution as follows

```
unsigned int start = clock();   

//run some stuff

int time_ = clock() - start;
cout<<"this took "<<time_<<" msecs.";
cin.get();
return 0;
```

in debug mode, the time is reflective of the complexity but in release mode, while it feels a bit faster than debug is showing 0 for the time no matter what,  is there setting that I'm not aware of?  thanks.

Comment: Are you sure your code's not compiled out when optimized? How long does it take in debug mode?

Comment: Mat has a good point about optimization. Have you tried making `start` volatile?